# Is membership of x in an infinite set decidable?

Tags: computability, decision-problem

In order to prove a certain function to be partially computable, I need to show an $\mathbb S$-program that computes it. I could really use the predicate $X \in B$ in my program to draw my conclusion. To give you the idea of what I am dealing with here it is one of my problems:

> Give an infinite set $B$ such that $\Phi(x,x)\uparrow$ for all $b \in
> B$ and such that $$H(x) = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if }
> \Phi(x,x)\downarrow \\ 0 \text{ if } x \in B \\ \uparrow \text{
> otherwise}\end{cases}$$ show that $H(x)$ is partially computable.

I am wondering if membership for infinite set is decidable and therefore can be used to write $\text{IF } X \in B$ such program. Am I allowed?

**Edit:** the notation $\Phi(x,x)\uparrow$ means the function is undefined.

Comment: It depends on the set. It is decidable whether a number belongs to the set of all primer. It is not decidable whether a number is the code of a total function. You should explain more carefully what your exact problem is. Also, the rest of the planet does not necessarily know what a "$\mathbb{S}$-program" might be (but we can also tell it doesn't matter).

Comment: Is the beginning of the second paragraph supposed to be "$B$ such that $\Phi(x,x)\uparrow$ for all $x \in B$"?

Comment: I am going to go in a limb here and guess that your set $B$ is assumed to be recursively enumerable. Then the whole thing becomes a homework, more or less.

Comment: Some infinite sets can be searched in finite time [see here](http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for your comments. $\mathbb S$ is a pseudo-language my textbook uses to show programs, but as you say it doesn't matter. Unfortunately no assumption has been made on $B$, so we can't think of it as recursive enumerable. In my question you can see an instance of the problems I have to solve, so that you could have a more detailed idea of what I am asking, hoping you could help me figure out the right way to give a good proof.

Comment: I don't believe you that there is no condition on $B$. Perhaps the exercise wants to know for which $B$ the given function is computable? Can you please double-check your exercise? The function is computable if, and only if, $B \cup H$ is r.e., where $H$ is the halting set.

Comment: @adrianN I can't tell whether I should be honored, amused, or disappointed that you're referring to my own blog (but a post written by a guest contributer).

Comment: One key point to see here is that you don't need decidability. If you do it right (exercise), non-terminating calls of *both* $\Psi(x,x)$ and $x \in B$ mean that $H(x) \uparrow$, but that's the specified behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed, in general, if we know nothing about the set $B$.

As Andrej Bauer explains in the comments: if the set $B$ is arbitrary and there are no guarantees about the set $B$ (as you state in the comments), then no, you cannot write "IF $X \in B$" in a program, as the predicate $X \in B$ might not be computable (depending upon the set $B$).

Re-reading your question, I see that you are allowed to choose a set $B$ of your choice (subject to some conditions).  If you're able to choose $B$ in a way that makes $B$ recursively enumerable, then $B$ is no longer completely arbitrary and you now have an additional condition on $B$ which makes this a straightforward homework (as Andrej Bauer also explains in the comments).